# css animation How to achieve changing width?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I want to keep left side of the box fixed, and increase its width with time so that the right hand side moves horizontally.

I wrote below code. You can try the animation at below link

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTCPP2062CMB

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;

}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px; transform: scale(0.1,1);}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:0px; top:0px; scale(0.1,1);}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:0px; top:0px; scale(0.1,1);}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:0px; scale(0.1,1);}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px; scale(0.1,1);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But it is keeping the centre of square as fixed and moving both sides. How do I keep one side fixed, and only move another horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin` to achieve this ([see MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)).

The `transform-origin` rule allows you to specify the point of reference (or origin) that a CSS transformation is applied from.

In your case, the key thing is that it your transform origin is relative to the left-hand-side of your `<div>`, which is achieved by setting the first coordinate of `transform-origin` to `0%` as shown below at both stages of the animation:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear; /* Add this */

}

@keyframes example {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        transform-origin: 0% 0%; /* Add this */
        transform: scale(0.1,1);
    }

    100% {
        background-color: yellow;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        transform-origin: 0% 0%; /* Add this */
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I put your code here. It doesnt seem to do anything - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTCQC9GBUKO0

Answer (score 2):

You can just animate the `width` instead of using `transform scale`.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; width: 0;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow;}
    50%  {background-color:blue;}
    75%  {background-color:green;}
    100% {background-color:red; width: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```